# keeping local changes in git

Tags: git, svn

I know this seems to have multiple duplicates but there is no real solution mentioned anywhere.

Let's put a real world example:

For testing, I've to load a model in my application 25 times a day. I'm getting a MessageBox that the model isn't created with the newest version of our software every time I load it. I know what I do so in my local copy I outcomment this check for faster testing. 
Of course I don't want to push this change, just keep it locally over the next few months or so while updating and adding new functionality to the project every day.
I want to do the same thing with different files in different situations, so the process should be easy and fast.

I've read about stashing, but as far as I get it, it basically means:

- stash (means save) your changes
- bring your working copy to a state that it only differs in what you want to push
- commit and push your changes
- restore your working copy to the previous state by reloading your stashed changes (stash pop)

This process has to be done every time you commit or update.

Hmmm... I mean, are they serious? 
In SVN you simply commit (means push) what you want to commit and leave all other things alone. Finished. If you update your working copy the changed file is merged of course. If there should be a conflict while merging (happens in 1 of 10000 cases) you are notified and must solve it. After you solved the conflict in your local copy updating works fine again. Done.

So the difference seems to be that SVN lets you decide what belongs to the shared repository while git demands that all repositories are always in the same state or will be after your commit/push. If you need different data you have to use complicated work arounds *all the time*.

Is that true or do I miss something here?

Comment: Well you could also just use branches. Create a branch for your changes, remove the lines of code you want to remove for your testing and you could also push this branches until you are finished with your stuff. After you finished you add the lines of code you removed prior and then merge it back to master. Simple workflow. Ahh before I forget. Do not, ever try to compare SVN and git. It's not possible.

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem. I want to keep the change over months without pushing it, but I want to be able to push other changes in the meantime.

Comment: Why not comparing source control systems? The are tools we use every day to solve the problem of collaboration, nothing else.

Comment: Well if you create a different branch and push everything there is no problem for me, because it's everything in a different branch.

Comment: Why would you compare two completely different systems? It's like comparing apples and pears. Doesn't make sense in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I misunderstand what you are asking, simply refrain from doing a `git add` on the files you do not want to commit (just as you would refrain from committing them in SVN). Alternatively, do a `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`, and your file will not be added when you do a `git add --all`.

Comment: The files in question are already in the repo. I just want to permanently keep a local change inside these files.

Comment: Yup, that's fine; `git add` is not just for adding files to the repo, it is also for adding the _latest_ version of a file to the index, which is what gets committed. So not calling `git add` on a file in git is the same as not committing the file in SVN. Totally counter intuitive, I know; git is not great when it comes to being intuitive.

Comment: And if you will really be keeping your local file for months, I would definitely suggest going the `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` route. That makes it actually _easier_ than SVN, since you don't have to remember to refrain from adding (committing) the file each time.